# Printing full-bleed from Adobe InDesign or Acrobat on Mac

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, adobe-acrobat

I'm using a Brother MFC-J6910DW inkjet.  On my PC it's easy enough to print full bleed, there's a borderless option in the printer dialog.  I can't find any such option on the Mac.  Am I not able to print to the edges in Adobe InDesign or Acrobat?

***UPDATE***: Apparently in Adobe InDesign you print by selecting the paper type with "(borderless)" next to the paper type you want (every supported paper type has 2 versions, 1 with and 1 without (borderless)).  Acrobat doesn't print full bleed, but Mac OS X's built-in preview tool has the same paper type option as Adobe InDesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full bleed (or "borderless" as printer manufacturers tend to call it) feature is a function of the printer driver. If the driver doesn't support it, then InDesign can't do it. You might check with Apple if there's an updated driver.